# Programmatically determine if a local geodatabase is File or Personal

Tags: arcobjects

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to distinguish between File and Personal Geodb workspace?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22471/how-to-distinguish-between-file-and-personal-geodb-workspace)

How can you determine whether a workspace is a file or personal geodatabase?  Using IWorkspace::Type you can determine wether the geodatabase is a local or remote, and using IDatabaseConnectionInfo2::ConnectionDBMS you can determined the DBMS for an SDE geodatabase.  However, I can find no class members that tell me directly whether a local goedatabase is File or Personal.  The only way I can see to do it is to retrieve the property set from IWorkspace.ConnectionProperties and evaluate the DATABASE property to see if the path string has a .gdb or .mdb extension.  My guess is that there is better way to do this, and I just haven't found the right interface.

Comment: This was asked before in this thread: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22471/how-to-distinguish-between-file-and-personal-geodb-workspace

Comment: Apologies for the duplicate question.  Searched for a posted question but obviously didn't search for the right terms.